# facebook Url regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, url, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I'm new to regular expression ,I'm trying to make data annotation for facebook url.so I want to accept urls like this:

> `https://www.facebook.com/{anything else}`

or

> `https://m.facebook.com/{anything else}`

i tried many solutions but none worked..

Comment: `^https://.*?.facebook.com/(.*)$` or `^https://(www|m).facebook.com/(.*)$` - I'm not sure what solutions you tried that didn't work.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Answer (score 2):

Might help:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(mbasic.facebook|m\.facebook|facebook|fb)\.(com|me)\/(?:(?:\w\.)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[\w\-\.]*\/)*([\w\-\.]*)/ig
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3ehqh)